# Download a zip file from eBay using rest-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client, ebay-api

I want to download the zip file from eBay. Using `downloadfile` api.

```
response = RestClient.post(url,xml,headers)
```

This call return the content of zip file that is not exractable in xml I think. So i want to download zip file as it is from eBay.

My code is:

```
headers = { 
 "X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME"=>"downloadFile",
 "X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-TOKEN" => access_token_lister,
 "X-EBAY-API-SITEID"=>"0",
 "Content-Type"=>"application/zip"
}
url = 'https://storage.ebay.com/FileTransferService' 

xml = '<?xml version="1.0" 
encoding="utf-8"?> <downloadFileRequest xmlns="ebay.com/marketplace/services">; <fileReferenceId>6637191637</fileReferenceId> <taskReferenceId>6474385857</taskReferenceId> </downloadFileRequest>'
```

The documentation for the API used above can be found here : http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/file-transfer/CallRef/downloadFile.html

Comment: If you want to download something you should probably use a GET method. Further, please show some more code on what you tried, and what error messages you received. We will not write the code for you ;)

Comment: @HolgerFrohloff I have update my question with code please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the content of the response to a library like [rubyzip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip). Then use it to extract your files from the zipped file. This you can do by first writing the file to disk, and then reading it using rubyzip.

Specifically look at this part of the documentation of rubyzip - [Reading a Zip file](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#reading-a-zip-file) to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There is not any option I have found in the 'rubyzip' documentation.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you are trying to extract the downloaded zip file, right ?

Comment: Yes. But the zip file is generated by me with the response which is return from the api call, and the respomse is in binery encoded form i have tried a lot to convert it in an other format like xml.